# How to enforce snake_case for properties with PHPCS?

Tags: php, phpcs

I am trying to find rule which will enforce ONLY properties to be in `$snake_case`

I have this for `CamelCase`:

```xml
<rule ref="Squiz.NamingConventions.ValidVariableName.NotCamelCaps"/>
```

Is there any full list of these rules and what they do? Cannot find them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up including [Wordpress Coding Standard](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards) and adding this rule:

```xml
<rule ref="WordPress.NamingConventions.ValidVariableName.VariableNotSnakeCase"/>
```